# Encoding / Decoding Data in Python 2.7, using Pandas and NLTK

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, utf-8, nltk, decode

I have a Pandas Dataframe and in one column is a german text, which i would like to analyse. But I have some trouble to encode/decode the text. I always get a wrong output.

My Script begins with this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

thats how i read my file (before i read it, it was saved with utf-8-sig (I dont know if this is necessery to know):

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/User/Documents/Reviews.CSV')
```

The output looks like that:

```
print df['REVIEW']

0       Wer einen großen, schicken Raum mag. Wer gern la...
1       Die L'Osteria residiert in einem alten Kino in...
2       Die Inneneinrichtung ist eine Erwähnung wert, ...
```

so far it works. But as soon I want to tokenize the text, with following code, i get a "messed up" output:

```
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
df['token'] = df['REVIEW'].apply(lambda x: tokenizer.tokenize(x))
```

Output:

```
print df['token']
0       [wer, einen, gro�, en, schicken, raum, mag wer,...
1       [die, losteria, residiert, in, einem, alten, k...
2       [die, inneneinrichtung, ist, eine, erw�, hnung...
```

I tried already to decode it:

```
df['token'].str.decode('utf-8')
```

and i tried to put this in the skript:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

but i still get the same output

I would like to get this output:

```
0       [wer, einen, großen, schicken, raum, mag, Wer, gern, la...
1       [die, l'Osteria, residiert, in, einem, alten, kino, in...
2       [die, inneneinrichtung, ist, eine, erwähnung, wert, ...
```

In case, someone can help me, here is a sample df:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( ['Ich bin ein Text, der sich nicht ändert','Wir zeigen größe','Manchmal brauchen wir mehr Übung.'])
df.columns =['REVIEW']
```

Comment: i can't reproduce this error on py 3

Comment: Did you try `df['REVIEW'].str.decode('utf8').apply(lambda x: tokenizer.tokenize(x))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NLTK tokenizers need Unicode as input](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize.html), and Unicode is not the default in Python2.7. You can use

```
df['REVIEW'].str.decode('utf8').apply(lambda x: tokenizer.tokenize(x))
```